# Codeigniter data not being passed from controller to view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have setup a codeigniter environment. I am able to pass data from my welcome controller to a view, but I created a new controller called TestController, and I cannot pass data to my test view. It says undefined variable.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: data
>
> Filename: views/gallery.php
>
> Line Number: 4

### Controller

```
<?php

class Testcontroller extends CI_Controller {


    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     *  The constructor
     */
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();  



    }


    function index() {


    $data = array('title' => 'My Title',
              'heading' => 'My Heading',
              'message' => 'My Message');

$this->load->view('test', $data);

    }
}

?>
```

### test view

```
<?php   var_dump($data); ?>
```

---

Comment: Did you research your problem at all? It seems to be rather basic.

Comment: you can watch [codeigniter documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/) for this type of basic questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$data` doesn't exist in the view. Instead you have one variable per key in the given array `$data`. So, in your case you have `$title`, `$heading` and `$message`.

Bear in mind that the passed data could be an anonymous array:

```
$this->load->view('test', array('title' => 'My Title',
              'heading' => 'My Heading',
              'message' => 'My Message'));
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to access the `$data` array in the view. Access the keys directly:

```
var_dump($title);
```

Comment: I see but why cannot I dump the entire $data array to see it's contents?

Comment: `$data` only exists as a local variable in the controller method.

Comment: If you want to place all the data in a single variable use: `$data['entire_data'] = array('title' => 'My title', 'heading' => 'My Heading');`

Answer (score 0):

In the view you can print like this:

```
<?php echo $title; ?>
<?php echo $heading; ?>
<?php echo $message; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Quick tip -- **Do not include the closing php tag in your Controllers or Models !**

```
} // bracket that closes class

 // NO NO NO
?>
```

Can mess up the files. the controller or model should end with the class closing bracket. 
you can put a comment if you want

```
} // heres a comment and its ok
```

Whereas in your view files - always close your php code.

Comment: What does it have to do with the question?

Comment: Look at his code example.