# A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined variable: result

Tags: php, codeigniter

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: result
>
> Filename: user/messages.php
>
> Line Number: 87
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: E:\xampp\htdocs\ci\application\views\user\messages.php Line: 87
>   Function: _error_handler
>
> File: E:\xampp\htdocs\ci\application\controllers\users\Dashboard.php
>   Line: 12 Function: view
>
> File: E:\xampp\htdocs\ci\index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once

**here is my code**
**Controller**

```
      <?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
        class Bills extends CI_Controller{
       function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
     }

     public function bill(){
     $id = $this->session->userdata('email');
     $this->load->database();
     $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url', 'html'));
     $this->load->model('fuser/Bill');
     $data['result'] = $this->Bill->bills();
     $this->load->view('user/messages',$data);
      }
      }
      ?>

**Model**

      <?php  
     class Bill extends CI_Model  
     {  
      function __construct()  
      {  
         // Call the Model constructor  
         parent::__construct();  
      }  
      //we will use the select function  
      public function bills($id)  
      {  
         //data is retrive from this query  

     $query = $this->db->get('invoices'); 
       return $query->result();   
      }  





      }  
     ?> 

**View**
      <div class="billing_tabs_text_part">
                <?php foreach($result as $row){?>
                  <p><?php echo $row['book_id']; }?></p>
                </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4261200/6521116)

Comment: i am not getting your answer

Comment: what give you `var_dump($data['result'])` in your bill() function ?

Comment: also remove id from `public function bills($id){`

Comment: @gopal removed $id from bills () not still same error

Comment: try <?php foreach($data['result'] as $row){?> in view

Comment: @Emad not working still same error

Comment: again try : $data = ['result' => $this->Bill->bills()];

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446700/codeigniter-passing-data-from-controller-to-view

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956512/codeigniter-data-not-being-passed-from-controller-to-view

Comment: @Emad did but same error

Comment: @shafiqul i did but still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am not sure which section is your problem so i suggest something how to find error

```
public function bill()
{
    echo 'ok'; // check controller work
    $id = $this->session->userdata('email');
    $this->load->database();
    echo 'ok1';
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url', 'html'));
    echo 'ok2';
    /*$this->load->model('fuser/Bill');
    $data['result'] = $this->Bill->bills();
    $this->load->view('user/messages', $data);*/
}
```

if this is print ok, ok1 , ok2 then this is query problem , if no print ok,ok1 then this is not query problem

in this case try to find error, if other ok then must print ok

```
public function bill()
{
    echo 'ok';
    /*$id = $this->session->userdata('email');
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url', 'html'));
    $this->load->model('fuser/Bill');
    $data['result'] = $this->Bill->bills();
    $this->load->view('user/messages', $data);*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `<?php echo $row->book_id; }?>` in view

because your data is object array.

Comment: the error is var $result not found. so basically it's the result part in view

Comment: @Praveen i did but not changing

Answer (score 0):

You need to find where the problem is exactly

try to `var_dump` the results and see if you're actually getting any results and that result is not a null or false;

so before this line:
$data['result'] = $this->Bill->bills();

try to

```
var_dump($this->Bill->bills());     
die();
```

if you're getting results try the other way using dummy content instead of $this->Bill->bills(); use :

$data['result'] = [0 => 1, 1 =>2]; and `var_dump` from the view

see if you're getting results, and in line where you have

```
  return $query->result();
```

make it like this:

```
  return $query->result() ? : [];
```

Comment: i am not getting any result after do that

Comment: if you're not getting results after  ? : [] ; and without any php warning
then most probably it's because the query is not returning any results in the first place, you need to debug the $db->get('invoices'); part, see if you have data there and look if the db->get is working as it should, you should be almost near the solution :)

Comment: return $query->result() ? : []; this means, that if $query->result() is `null` or `false` it will return an empty array instead, assuming the result should always be `array` and not false or null

Answer (score 0):

What gives you $query->result(); try to print in model itself

Comment: i am not getting you

Comment: this is not answer, this comment section

Answer (score 0):

don't return  , print and check the result
ex: 
var_dump($query->result());